# cdkDropList doesn't save new order of items

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-7

I have a super simple drop list in my angular project:

```
<ul cdkDropList style="padding: 20px;">
    <li cdkDrag>111111</li>
    <li cdkDrag>222222</li>
    <li cdkDrag>333333</li>
    <li cdkDrag>444444</li>
    <li cdkDrag>555555</li>
</ul>
```

However, when I drag `111111` to the end, it jumps back to being first in the list.

- Here's a [video demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsSri.jpg) of the problem.
- Here's a [re-creation](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eiz5su?file=app/cdk-drag-drop-sorting-example.html) of my problem on StackBlitz.

Comment: Could you throw together an example on stack blitz?

Comment: @Trevor https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eiz5su?file=app/cdk-drag-drop-sorting-example.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a **data source**.

After Dragging, you must update that data source to reflect your UI.

It is jumping back to your **real** modal state.

**Example:**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="box-list" cdkDropList (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
  <div class="drag-box" *ngFor="let customer of customers" cdkDrag>
    {{customer.name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

**TS file:**

```
import { CdkDragDrop, moveItemInArray } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
...
export class SortListComponent implements OnInit {
  customers = [
    { name: 'Adam', age: 23 },
    { name: 'Jack', age: 27 },
    { name: 'Katherin', age: 26 },
    { name: 'John', age: 30 },
    { name: 'Watson', age: 42 },
  ];

  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    moveItemInArray(this.customers, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
  }
}
```

Notice my **customers** is my data source. And I am updating it after drop

Comment: I can't just hard-code my list items? It must have a data model?

Comment: If you would like to change position, yes. The template does not have a state it can update. It's only a view

Comment: Interesting. Thank you!